# Doorkeeper gem vs knock gem

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper

Can anyone help me understand the difference between doorkeeper and knock gems?  Could I do jwt token auth with doorkeeper, or vice versa do oauth 2 with knock?  Could I use both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The knock gem merely provides authorization using the JWT tokens.  Think of this as the replacement for using cookies for browser based applications. Doorkeeper is a full Oauth 2.0 provider that can use Knock as the JWT token generator.